# How to get all active states & provinces from one api call?

Tags: api, javascript

I would like to get all active (i.e., in countryLimit) states & provinces available in my site for use in HTML tag. Can I query for that with a single JavaScript call to CRM.api3?

I've tried:

```
CRM.api3('Setting', 'get', {
```

"sequential": 1,
"return": ["countryLimit"],
"api.StateProvince.get": {}

but that just gives me two unrelated arrays. Can I join them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
CRM.api3('StateProvince', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": ["name","country_id.name"],
  "options": {"limit":0}
})
```

UPDATE: I haven't tried this but `Lodash` v3 is loaded on most civi pages so you might be able to use [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#filter) or [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#forEach) to combine the results of the above with the countryLimit array to remove inactive ones.

Comment: Thanks. You've helped me realize I left something out of my question. I need to limit the results by 'active' countries, which I think means in countryLimit. Your answer gives my all the StateProvince records in the database. I need to filter for active countries.

Comment: Thanks, again. Would that involve a separate api call? I'm really trying to keep all this in a single call.

Comment: Yes I think so since you'd need to get countryLimit separately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer since this might work for you better. In your extension in hook_civicrm_buildForm do something like this. I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere but the country/state chain will do some autowiring for you if your fields are named in a special way.

```
function myextension_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'The_Form_Name') {
    $form->add('select', 'country', ts('Country'), CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::country());
    $form->addChainSelect('state_province');
    CRM_Core_Region::instance('form-body')->add(array(
     'template' => 'CRM/Myextension/my.tpl',
    ));
  }
```

Then in CRM/Myextension/my.tpl something like:

```
<tr><td class="label">{$form.country.label}</td>
<td>{$form.country.html}</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">{$form.state_province.label}</td>
<td>{$form.state_province.html}</td></tr>
```

You may have to fiddle a bit but this will automatically apply the countryLimit and connect the two fields.

Comment: Thanks, again, but I'm trying to keep this 100% JavaScript.

Comment: Ok have updated the javascript one with an idea.